# Making a counter if a row is different than the previous one

Tags: r

I know you can use in R

```
tail()
```

and

```
head()
```

to count when a specific value is different from the previous one, but can I do this for multiple columns? I need to make a column that counts 1 if the current row (LAST 4 COLUMNS ONLY) is different than the previous one.

here is an example of my data:

```
>    Standing Stepping Cycling New_Sitting
1         0        0       0           1
2         0        0       0           1
3         0        0       0           1
4         0        0       0           1
5         0        0       0           1
6         0        0       0           1
7         0        0       0           1
8         0        0       0           1
9         0        0       0           1
10        0        0       0           1
11        0        0       0           1
12        0        0       0           1
13        0        0       0           1
14        0        0       0           1
15        0        0       0           1
16        0        0       0           1
17        0        0       0           1
18        0        0       0           1
19        0        0       0           1
20        0        0       0           1
21        0        0       0           1
22        0        0       0           1
23        0        0       0           1
24        0        0       0           1
25        0        0       0           1
26        0        0       0           1
27        0        0       0           1
28        0        0       0           1
29        0        0       0           1
30        0        0       0           1
31        0        0       0           1
32        0        0       0           1
33        0        0       0           1
34        0        0       0           1
35        0        0       0           1
36        0        0       0           1
37        0        0       0           1
38        0        0       0           1
39        0        0       0           1
40        0        0       0           1
41        0        0       0           1
42        0        0       0           1
43        0        0       0           1
44        0        0       0           1
45        0        0       0           1
46        0        0       0           1
47        0        0       0           1
48        0        0       0           1
49        0        0       1           0
50        0        1       0           0
```

So basically, the last 4 columns represent the posture of the person, I need to have a column that counts (named counter, or anything else logical) that is 1 when they change position, 0 when they don't. Let me know if you need more information.

In this case the answer should be:

```
count = 2
```

Comment: yes, so the last 4 columns will always be 3 "0" and 1 "1", I need to know how many times that "1" changes positions between the last 4 columns

Comment: Well I need a column, that shows "0" if the the current values of the last 4 columns of THE SAME ROW are different than the last rows 4 columns

Comment: So if you look at the last 4 columns that I've shown, there should be a single value of 1 and three values of 0, that single value of 1 shows what the person wearing the sensor was doing. I need to know how often do they change what they are doing, so basically counting how often does the 4 numbers to the right of a row is different than the previous row

Comment: ok let me post another data set that is more simple to understand

Comment: I updated the data, I need a way to count how often is a row different than the previous one. The answer here should be "2" since the rows only changed twice at the bottom of this data set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245188/discussion-between-richard-michaud-langis-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to check whether `any` of the columns selected meets the condition for a row, use `if_any` or if we want `all` the columns to meet, then it is `if_all` - loop over the columns selected with `last_col()`, then check whether the current value is not equal to previous (`lag`), and convert the logical to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Counter = +(if_any((last_col()-3):last_col(), 
        ~ .x != lag(.x, default= first(.x)))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = 1:50, Time = c("2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:00", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:01", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:02", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:03", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:04", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:05", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:06", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:07", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:08", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:09", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:10", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:11", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:12", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:13", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:14", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:15", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:16", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:17", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:18", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:19", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:20", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:21", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:22", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:23", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:24", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:25", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:26", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:27", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:28", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:29", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:30", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:31", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:32", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:33", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:34", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:35", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:36", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:37", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:38", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:39", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:40", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:41", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:42", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:43", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:44", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:45", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:46", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:47", "2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:48", 
"2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:49"), Axis1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 105L, 34L, 98L, 81L, 
69L, 44L, 36L, 70L, 75L, 33L, 34L, 16L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
84L, 53L), Axis2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 65L, 42L, 15L, 15L, 108L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 
119L, 92L, 21L, 11L, 0L, 17L, 59L, 40L, 28L, 30L, 46L), Axis3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 
1L, 54L, 19L, 93L, 98L, 209L, 40L, 48L, 14L, 19L, 40L, 22L, 14L, 
36L, 47L, 8L, 116L, 17L), VM = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
124.28, 54.05, 112.89, 84.54, 158.35, 138.24, 230, 120.83, 148.63, 
98.74, 44.25, 44.46, 22, 22.83, 69.84, 61.72, 29.12, 146.33, 
72.21), Standing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stepping = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cycling = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L), New_Sitting = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand where to put my column names, I need "Stepping", "Standing", "Cycling", and "New_Sitting", Also does the code you provide create a new column ? maybe one named "Counter"?

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis i created the column as `flag` instead of `Counter`.  Changed it to Counter.  Regarding the names, I didn't use it because you r post is looking for indexing instead of names.  So i used `last_col()` to create the column index

Comment: Weirdly this is now giving me a single column of 1s and 0s

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis No idea,  It worked with both your examples in creating a `Counter` column

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis you can check the `str(yourdata)` and see if there is any issue in the column types compared to the one you showed as examples

Comment: Managed to fix it, removed the ```pull()``` section you had mentioned before

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis `pull` i used to extract the column.  It was just to show the value of the column